# mysql on wamp server doesnt work

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

i have just installes wamp server 2.4 and almost everything is working good but every time i am trying to open a file with mysql code on it he just showing me a white page whith nothing on it.
this is one of my files i have tried to open 'phpmyadmin' and this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>Untitled Document</title> </head>

<body> <?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "guycohen801", "") or die ("cant connect to the server");

$db = mysql_select_db("test", $connect) or die ("cant select database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM asd3"; $result = mysql_query($query, $connect) or die ("query failed:" . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {     

echo $row['1']," "; echo $row['2']," <br>";

}

mysql_close($connect); ?>

</body> </html>
```

and on the local host he shows me a whilte page and when i cliced on 'view page sorce' that what was writen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
```

how can i fix this problem?????????????

Comment: avoid using mysql_ function. its depreciated. another thing is there is no problem with view source. as browser never shows php code.

Comment: yes but even 'phpmyadmin' doeasnt work and it also shows just a white page.and onother thing is that the <body> and <html> are not cloesed.

Comment: about <body> and <html> you need to close it in your code. are you doing it.

Comment: yes you can see that in the code in my question

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** write new applications with `mysql_query`. It's being removed from future versions of PHP. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Comment: thank you i am just learning now and my book is old

Comment: What colour is your WampManager icon? Thats the `W` icon that sits in the System Tray!